# C++ Malloc Assertion Failure unless I insert a new line prior?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a beginner coding task, which has me iterate through an integer array and duplicate any 0's. My code in a separate terminal looks like this:

```
    vector<int> arr{1,0,1,2,3,0,4,5,0};
    int size = arr.size();

    for(int i : arr)        //display original list and size
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nSize is " << size << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            for(int j = size; j >= i; j--)
            {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[i] = 0;
            i++;
            size++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)     //display new list and size
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nSize is " << size << endl;
```

This program will compile and run and spit out the following, as expected:

1 0 1 2 3 0 4 5 0
Size is 9
1 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 4 5 0 0
Size is 12

HOWEVER, if I remove the first for-loop which displays the original size and list, the program will compile, but attempting to run the program will output the following:

> a.out: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
> (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
> prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
> 0)' failed.Aborted

If I remove the loop which displays my new array, the error will not occur, but since there will be no output, I don't get what I need. What exactly is this error? Also, if I remove the first for-loop and instead, replaced it with a simple `cout << endl;` it will run without the error.

Comment: `arr[j + 1] = arr[j];` with `j` starting at `size` is UB;  And `size++;` is also giving me cause for concern.

Comment: You're `for(int j = size; j >= i; j--)` loop is breaching your vector limits. With that comes *undefined behavior*, and with *that* stops any sensibility in trying to determine whatever behavior you're observing (because it literally has no definition to start with).

Comment: @RichardCritten Is there a way for me to add a new index in a vector so that I can safely store a value at arr[ j + 1 ]?

Comment: @WhozCraig How come the program will still compile and run if and only if I keep the first loop, if the main purpose of it is just to display the original list?

Comment: @maboo A program compiles as soon as it is syntactically correct. But that does not guarantee that it is logically correct.

Comment: @maboo Undefined Behaviour means that trying to analyse the program is pointless.  All we can do is point out the source of the UB and hope you update (or post another) question once the UB is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to you do not change `arr` size.

```
            for(int j = size; j >= i; j--)
            {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
```

This loop does not change the size of `arr` vector, and simply place elements outside of allocated memory buffer.

Look at [vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that should do a trick with inserting elements and increasing the size of underline buffer.

Comment: there is a bug... the iterator can be invalidated by the insert

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of vector:

```
for(int j = size; j >= i; j--)
{
    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
}
```

in this case arr is a vector, but you are not increment the size of it, you just add element in a space of memory not allocated. This can cause segmentation fault.

You should use the [std::vector::insert](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-insert-function-in-c-stl/).

The right code should be this:

```
    vector<int> arr{1,0,1,2,3,0,4,5,0};
    int size = arr.size();

    for(int i : arr)        //display original list and size
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nSize is " << size << endl;

   for (int i=0; i< arr.size();i++){
        if (arr[i]==0){ 
            arr.insert(arr.begin()+i+1,0);
            arr.pop_back();
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)     //display new list and size
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nSize is " << size << endl;
```